# RobotFramework seleniumlibrary open headless browser in network namespace

Tags: selenium, firefox, namespaces, robotframework

I need to use network namespaces in my setup, and it is working just fine.
However, when it comes to testing via seleniumLibrary to open a browser and test webinterface, i can't seem to get it to work with network namespaces.

I can manually run firefox in namespace by running `firefox` in the namespace, that has access the the network the namespace is assigned. 
How do i do this in RobotFramework with seleniumLibrary?

I have this atm:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation   Test browser access in netns

Library   OperatingSystem
Library   SeleniumLibrary

Force Tags  test_123

*** Test Cases ***
Test Browser In Netns
    Open Browser    192.168.0.100  browser=ff
    Close Browser
```

Running this produces the error: \

```
WebDriverException: Message: Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 69 
  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mci/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/SeleniumLibrary/__init__.py", line 492, in run_keyword
    return DynamicCore.run_keyword(self, name, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/mci/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/robotlibcore.py", line 103, in run_keyword
    return self.keywords[name](*args, **(kwargs or {}))
  File "/home/mci/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/SeleniumLibrary/keywords/browsermanagement.py", line 293, in open_browser
    return self._make_new_browser(
  File "/home/mci/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/SeleniumLibrary/keywords/browsermanagement.py", line 324, in _make_new_browser
    driver = self._make_driver(
  File "/home/mci/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/SeleniumLibrary/keywords/browsermanagement.py", line 716, in _make_driver
    driver = self._webdriver_creator.create_driver(
  File "/home/mci/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/SeleniumLibrary/keywords/webdrivertools/webdrivertools.py", line 83, in create_driver
    return creation_method(
  File "/home/mci/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/SeleniumLibrary/keywords/webdrivertools/webdrivertools.py", line 199, in create_firefox
    return webdriver.Firefox(
  File "/home/mci/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/mci/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/home/mci/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(
```

Running this outside network namespace produces no errors, and goes through 100% pass.

Comment: What do you mean under network namespaces? Are you planning to run tests with Selenium Grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loopback is not automatically added and up'ed when creating netns. 
This needs to be added with `ip netns exec net-$name ip link set dev lo up`. 
GeckoDriver will try to bind itself to a random port on 127.0.0.1, so without `lo` being up, it will naturally fail.